# Incremental scatter plot in c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I need to display data points in a scatter plot using c3.js. The data points arrive in batches, and I want to update the plot incrementally as the new points arrive.

The first batch is given while initializing the plot, and displays fine. But when I use flow to update the plot, the earlier points get erased. Also, the X axis does not display the correct X coordinates. [Edit: added clarification] After the flow, the points appear at (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1) and not (1.5, 1), (2.5, 1), (3.5, 1) as specified in the data.]

Am I missing something?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cornea/b33usb69/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'A',
        columns: [
            ['A', 1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
            ['B', 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
        ],
        type: 'scatter',
        types: { 'B': 'scatter' }
    },
    axis: {
        x: { label: 'A', tick: { fit: true } },
        y: { label: 'B' }
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.flow({
        columns: [
            ['A', 1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
            ['B', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        ]
    });
}, 2000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since your `x` values don't change, I think in this case you need to set `data.x` and possibly use `ids:` to unload and flush the chart as in the [C3.js XY chart example](http://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy.html) in order to get the effect you want.

Comment: Answer should have been a comment.

Comment: The problem of the old points getting erased when the new ones were shown is resolved by setting `length = 0` in the flow specification. The points added by the "flow" are still displayed incorrectly, though. [Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornea/b33usb69/5/)

Comment: Updated answer - no joy. If you find a workaround you can post an answer to your own question and accept it.  I would vote up any useful response. If you post a link to your question here on the C3.js mailing list other users may have a simpler way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the scale of your Y axis shifts so much in your example (a 50% drop in the values) you will probably need to set `axis: { y: { min: 0 },  y: { max: 2 } }` to see the scatter points move. Try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrutm37z/52/) to see if that change does what you want.

The X axis values are updated when you use `chart.flow` if you change that to load and reload the chart data with `chart.load({ ... })` they will stay the same. To get a chart to flow data properly there's a little more work required to initialize the X axis values (see the [flow API example](http://c3js.org/samples/api_flow.html)) but it's not clear from your simple example that this is what you want to do.

---

**Edit**:

Thanks for your clarification.  I can't answer your question with working code but see [github #865 issue for C3.js](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/865) which is related to your problem.

You might want to consider using a different approach to the data and avoiding `flow` in order to construct a suitable chart.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was that the old points are erased when the new ones were shown. I could resolve the same by setting `length = 0` in the flow specification. Updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cornea/b33usb69/5/

The remaining issue is that after the flow, the points appear at (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1) and not (1.5, 1), (2.5, 1), (3.5, 1) as specified in the data. (Sorry for not being clear earlier).

Comment: +1 for pointing out [github #865 issue for C3.js](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/865). Will wait for that issue to be resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using `.flow`, isn't that more for time-series data?

Can't you just use `.load` to get the new data points onto the chart?

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/b33usb69/20/

EDIT:

If you want it in the same array, then something like this:
(code not tested)

```
var a = ['A_x', 1.5, 2.5, 3.5], b = ['A', 2.0, 2.0, 2.0];

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xs: { A: 'A_x' },
        columns: [
             ['A_x', 1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
            ['A', 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
        ],
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    axis: {
        y: { min: 0, max: 3 }
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    a = a.concat[1.5, 2.5, 3.5];
    b = b.concat[1.0, 1.0, 1.0];
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            a,
            b
        ]
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to append to the same series, not add a new one. Changing B -> A and B_x -> A_x in your jsfiddle shows the issue -- the older points get deleted when the new ones are added.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The chart.load will replot the earlier points over and over again -- this is inefficient. The chart.flow method plots the new data incrementally.